# Como trocar conteúdo sem trocar a estrutura?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysqli

Comecei a fazer um site no código mesmo. Só que esse site vai ter várias páginas em que em toda página, a estrutura é a mesma, o que muda é apenas o conteúdo. Pra não ter que fazer no código página por página, fazer um monte de páginas, eu quero usar uma estrutura padrão fazendo `include` com `php` e pegando o conteúdo no `mysql`.

Exemplo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= <- estrutura padrão | define conteúdo -> KPlPa07KBR0

https://www.facebook.com/pg <- estrutura padrão | define conteúdo -> /zulaxcloud/

Comment: Geralmente para fazer esse tipo de coisa se usa um framework MVC. Como por exemplo, o [Laravel](https://laravel.com).

Comment: @LuizFelipe tem alguma outro opção?

Comment: Não entendi qual a dúvida? Está com problemas nos `include`s?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam na verdade eu queria fazer uma estrutura só para vários conteúdos. Por exemplo: www.meuseite.com/pg1 - www.meuseite.com/pg2 - www.meuseite.com/pg3
No caso, ele vai usar a mesma estrutura, mesmo template para as 3 páginas, o que vai mudar seria apenas o conteúdo.

Comment: E qual o problema, o que você não está conseguindo fazer? A única coisa que precisa é um index com o layout e design, as consultas e os include

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam eu já tenho a página padrão, as consultas e os includes. Mas como que eu vou criar um link para acessar um tipo de conteúdo usando a página padrão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você já tem tudo pronto, você pode configurar o arquivo `.htaccess` para criar uma url amigável, como o próprio stackoverflow usa, um exemplo simples:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^pagina/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?pagina=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Isso fará com que páginas `examplo.com/pagina/n`, sendo n qualquer número inteiro, sejam redirecionadas para `index.php`, lá você pode pegar a página com o get e usar para buscar os dados no banco

```
<?php
    echo $_GET["pagina"];
?>
```

Para entender melhor como usar o arquivo `.htaccess` veja [esse artigo](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis-com-regras-complexas)

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu precisava. Obrigado!